# How do I convert this Python for loop into a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am writing code to randomly roll a die and then return the amount of times each number is rolled.

I got this to work as a function, but I want to know how I could convert this to a list comprehension.

This is the function I am using:

```
results = []
for roll_num in range(1000):
    result = die.roll()
    results.append(result)
```

Note that `roll()` is a method I made in a class for a die.

The closest I get for a working list comprehension is:

```
result = die.roll()
results = [result for value in range(1000)]
```

which does roll the die but it only **rolls one number 1,000 times** instead of six numbers a random amount adding up to 1,000 times.

So can this for loop be to turned into a list comprehension, if so how?

Comment: Thinking about the `collections.Counter`

Comment: Why did you put `result = die.roll()` outside the list copmrehension? In any case, yes, this can be directly converted, `[die.roll() for roll_num in range(1000)]`, although, in both the loop and the comprehension, `_` would idiomatically be used instead of `roll_num` for a variable that is not meant tobe used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have it?

`results = [random.randint(1,6) for value in range(10)]` works, so

`results = [die.roll() for value in range(1000)]` should as well.

The only problem is you had assigned die.roll(), which resulted in result being the primitive return value rather than a function call.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```py
results = [die.roll() for _ in range(1000)]
```

Note that `_` is commonly used as a stand-in for a value you don't really care about.